# Nltk classify based on single parameter

Tags: python, nltk

I am trying to use NaiveBayesClassifier to classify times spent in some areas of the smart home.

My training data looks like this:

```
[[{'time': '00:00'}, 'IN'], [{'time': '00:01'}, 'IN'], [{'time': '00:02'}, 'OUT'], [{'time': '00:03'}, 'OUT'], [{'time': '00:04'}, 'OUT'], [{'time': '00:05'}, 'OUT'], [{'time': '00:06'}, 'OUT'], ......,  [{'time': '08:06'}, 'IN'], [{'time': '08:07'}, 'IN'], [{'time': '08:08'}, 'IN'], ... ]
```

This is my code:

```
classifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(training_data)

start_date = datetime.strptime('2010-11-19 00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
end_date = datetime.strptime('2010-11-19 23:59', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')

test_data = []
while start_date < end_date:
    test_data.append(dict(time=start_date.strftime('%H:%M')))
    start_date += timedelta(0, 60)

test = classifier.classify_many(test_data)
print(test)
```

Result looks like this:

```
['OUT', 'OUT', 'OUT', 'OUT', 'OUT', 'OUT', 'OUT', 'OUT', 'OUT',....]
```

I never get `'IN'` as a result. Can someone see something wrong with my classifier?

Comment: How many observations do you have in the training set and what's the percentange of IN in total ?

Comment: @MedAli 11.6% are IN. 21626 observation in total, 2269 are IN

Comment: You are trying to create a classifier in an unbalanced dataset, NaiveBayesClassifier is not a best fit for that. Start by checking this tutorial : http://machinelearningmastery.com/tactics-to-combat-imbalanced-classes-in-your-machine-learning-dataset/

Comment: @MedAli That is a great answer! The problem is in my datasets. I changed datasets to be different - so I just show `IN` if it is detected motion within the hour and `OUT` if not. @MedAli please add answer to the question.

Comment: You've already added an answer so you can accept your answer :).

Answer (score 0):

As MedAli suggested, the problem is in my dataset that has only 11% of `IN`, so I had to adjust my dataset according to: http://machinelearningmastery.com/tactics-to-combat-imbalanced-classes-in-your-machine-learning-dataset/

I changed my dataset, so it is now having only hourly based data (if sensor was activated during an hour, it is added as `IN`).

This is not the perfect solution, but it was good enough for my case.